# Как изменить duration по клику?

Tags: android, аудио

Доброго времени суток! Я написал простенький аудиоплеер. Всё работает отлично, но недавно захотел реализовать одну фишку, которая есть во вконтактовском аудиоплеере: время воспроизведения песни меняется по клику на него (отображается либо текущее время воспроизведения либо общее время, которое уменьшается во время прослушивания). Так вот: как сие реализовать?

Вот код для код активити, где отображаем `duration`:

```
 private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        // Displaying Total Duration time
        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.getReversedProgressPercentage(currentDuration,totalDuration));
        // Displaying time completed playing
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

`getProgressPercentage()` для отображения текущего времени воспроизведения,а `getReversedProgressPercentage()` отображает `totalDuration`,который уменьшается по ходу воспроизведения.

Новый вариант Runnable с меняющимся по клику duration:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    final long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    final long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.getReversedProgressPercentage(currentDuration,totalDuration));
    songTotalDurationLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isCurrent) {
                isCurrent = false;
                songTotalDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
            } else {
                isCurrent = true;
                songTotalDurationLabel.setText("" + utils.getReversedProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
            }

        }

    });

        int progress =(int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
   handler.postDelayed(this, 4000);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю нужно вынести часть переменных вне класса, так будет хранится их состояние. Привязываешь клик - меняешь состояние. Если я правильно понял вопрос конечно.

Еще можно привязать к прогресс-бару обработчик, который будет получать тек значание и менять твою переменную или несколько.

Comment: спасибо,я сделал в Runnable я изменил(см.выше),totalduration меняется на currentduration,но из-за handler-a опять возвращается в исходное состояние(totalduration),может как-то можно handler переделать?

Comment: я хз, какая у вас логика в коде просто...такие вещи не спрашивайте. Все что можно и нужно менять из вне - выносите в переменные класса(активити самого).

Comment: понял,спасибо за совет